# Какой тип данных для путей картинок в PSQL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, yii2

Нужно выводить на страницу с товаром соответствующую этому товару картинку. Создал папку с картинками: frontend/web/Pic. Картинки переименовал в id'шник, равный id'шнику товара. Теперь хочу спросить, как правильно хранить такой путь (писать полный путь начиная с корня D:\ или начиная с коренной папки /web/Pic) и какой тип данных должен быть? Где-то читал, что тип данных должен быть "BLOB", но в Postgres такого типа данных тупо нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> в Postgres такого типа данных тупо нет.

Есть.

Но хранить картинки в таком формате нет смысла.

> как правильно хранить такой путь

хранить надо относительный путь (даже без /web/Pic), чтобы при переименовании проекта или переносе проекта в другую директорию ничего не сломалось. Просто внутри проекта должно быть настроено, что при написании `/product/1/photo.jpg` картинка бралась из нужного места